# Append reversed dataframe to original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse

does anyone know how to append a reverse dataframe to a given dataframe? I am representing paths. Each unique `id` stands for one path in the dataframe. Given the columns `x,y,t,id,frequency` I want to reverse mainly the `x,y`values and append them to the input dataframe. The `id` should go on increasing and the `frequency` can stay the same as in the original. 
I mean it is not really a clean reverse but more like in the example here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,2,9,9], 'y':[1,2,2,100,101],'t':[1,2,3,1,2],'id':[1,1,1,2,2]},'frequency':[5,5,5,1,1]})
x   y   t   id   frequency
1   1   1   1     5
1   2   2   1     5
2   2   3   1     5
9  100  1   2     1
9  101  2   2     1
```

should become:

```
x   y   t   id   frequency
1   1   1   1     5
1   2   2   1     5
2   2   3   1     5
9  100  1   2     1
9  101  2   2     1
-------------------   ---> here begins the reverse
2   2   1   3     5
1   2   2   3     5
1   1   3   3     5
9  101  1   4     1
9  100  2   4     1
```

I tried some approaches but could not find a solution. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting your original frame then appending it to the original frame:

```
df.append(df.sort_values(by = 'frequency'))
```

Comment: Glad if it helped. Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this now. Apart from column `t` everything as I want it to be

```
import pandas as pd    
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,2,9,9], 'y':[1,2,2,100,101],'t':[1,2,3,1,2],'id':[1,1,1,2,2],'frequency':[5,5,5,1,1]})
df2= df1[::-1]
id_amount=df2['id'].nunique()
df2['id'] = df2['id'].apply(lambda x: x + id_amount)   
df2=df2.sort_values(by=['id'])
df1=df1.append(df2)
```

Comment: what if  you do `df1.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=True)`